# How do I run inference on a Sagemaker endpoint?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

I am using AWS Sagemaker and Python to deploy an endpoint for a machine learning model, specifically to run inference on a set of image chips. However, when I execute the script to perform the inference, I get an error stating that the model container header exceeds a specified number of bytes. Below is a sample image (array) I am using to test the script and the output message captured.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.ones([2,320,320,1], dtype=np.uint8)
      
from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor, numpy_deserializer, NumpySerializer, NumpyDeserializer
predictor = Predictor(endpoint_name_serialzer=NumpySerializer(), deserializer=NumpyDeserizlier())
result=predictor.predict(arr)
print(result.shape)

-> Error in <virtual_env>/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker/predictory.py in line 161
response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
  
ModelError:  An error occurred (modelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: 
Received server error (O) from model with message "Response received from the model container 
has headers with length greater than 4096 bytes.  Reduce the length of your containers's 
response headers and update your endpoint  See https://us-iso-east- 
1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-iso-east- 
1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/ModelTest-mdl-1 in account 12345679012"
```

The error I receive occurs when trying to use the prediction function against the endpoint for "result=predictor.predict(arr)". I am trying to otherwise find examples of Sagemaker model container headers, but I am not having much luck. Any assistance is most appreciated.

Comment: What are you returning in the header that is greater than 4096 bytes?  Is this a custom container you are using? Have you tried reducing the data you are sending back in the header ?

Comment: @MarcKarp - Thank you for your insights.  Part of my question is ignorance on my part, as I cannot confirm where to find the model container header.  I am searching in the "predictor.py" file but do not see anything specific regarding headers or header responses.  My pytorch model (.pth) that is being used is has a byte length of about 50 bytes and the docker container to which the outputs are written is less than 70 bytes so I'm just struggling to confirm where I need to look?

Answer (score 0):

1.You can try trimming unnecessary response headers, Remove any headers that are not essential.By reducing the number and size of headers, you can bring them within the allowed limit.

2.You can compress headers, If you have large headers consider compressing them.

Comment: @yashawsi kakumanu - Thank you for your suggestion, but as stated above I am not sure where I need to look to compress the headers?  Is this within the pytorch model (.pth), or the docker container itself?